# Multiple instances of simple audio player

Tags: javascript, audio

I've been playing with this code for a simple audio player but I noticed that it only allows one player on the page (The second button doesn't work). It does use classes rather than ids but perhaps using querySelector is an issue.  Ideally I would like to have several on the page so was wondering how I would go about this using this style of coding (i.e. using font awesome without JQuery).

```
<audio src="http://bornemark.se/bb/mp3_demos/PoA_Sorlin_-_Stay_Up.mp3" class="sound" loop></audio>
<a href="#" class="button"><i class="fa fa-play" aria-hidden="true"></i></a> <br>

<audio src="http://bornemark.se/bb/mp3_demos/PoA_Sorlin_-_Stay_Up.mp3" class="sound" loop></audio>
<a href="#" class="button"><i class="fa fa-play" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>

    <script>
      document.querySelector(`.button`).addEventListener(`click`, event => {
      let icon = document.querySelector(`.button i`); 
      let sound = document.querySelector(`.sound`);

      icon.classList.toggle(`fa-pause`);
      icon.classList.toggle(`fa-play`);

       if (icon.classList.contains(`fa-pause`)) {
        sound.play();
        } 
      else {
        sound.pause();
      }
    });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the main issue is with querySelector as this will only get the first instance of .sound. querySelectorAll would return an array of all .sound elements, but this wouldn't work either. It probably wouldn't play anything at all.

I would suggest you go with your other suggestion of using IDs and a data- attribute on the button which references the ID of the audio target, so it knows which audio element to bind to. Something like this should work:

```
<audio id="audio-1" src="address/of/file" loop></audio>
<i data-audio-target="audio-1" class="audio-button fa fa-play"></i><br/>

<audio id="audio-2" src="address/of/file" loop></audio>
<i data-audio-target="audio-2" class="audio-button fa fa-play"></i>

<script>
  document.addEventListener('click', event => {

    // Do nothing if the target was not an .audio-button
    if (!event.target.classList.contains('audio-button'))
      return false;

    // If the target was an .audio-button
    let button = event.target;
    let audioTarget = button.getAttribute('data-audio-target'); // Gets the ID of the audio element that you want to start
    let sound = document.getElementById(audioTarget);

    button.classList.toggle(`fa-pause`);
    button.classList.toggle(`fa-play`);

    if (button.classList.contains(`fa-pause`)) {
      sound.play();
    } 
    else {
      sound.pause();
    }
  });
</script>
```

Comment: I am not familiar using data attributes so am getting a bit lost trying to get it work. May I ask how I would use a data- attribute on the button to reference the ID of the audio target.

Comment: Sure, data- attributes are basically custom tags that you can place on html elements which are useful for storing extra information - [see this MDN link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes). I've updated the code to use more of your example to put it in context.

Comment: Thanks. That looks great however the icons aren't appearing for me. I thought it may be because class="fa fa-play" wasn't added in the <audio> element but when I added it the player stopped working??

Comment: I tried to minimise the code in my example to emphasise the usage of data-* attribute. The class would need to be on the element that acts as the button, not the audio element. I've update the example to show a way you might implement the classes. It's quite similar to your original example.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `<a>` and wrap the `<i>` around the `<audio>` tag. It sound weird but an interactive element like an `<a>` or `<audio>` is easier to hook into with a phasing element like `<i>`. Details are commented in demo.

BTW, you may get an error when playing video or audio and something about Promises. I've added the fix for that error and may you have to use it whenever you have audio/video on a page. This is not a bug, it's a feature . [See this article for details](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/03/play-returns-promise)

#### Demo

```css
i {
  display: block;
  padding: 3px 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  line-height: 1.4;
  width: 99%;
  background: linear-gradient(#88C1FF, #3E7EBD, #88C1FF);
  box-shadow: -3px 3px 5px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  ;
}

i:hover {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 0, 0.8);
  text-shadow: 2px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  background: rgb(62, 126, 189);
  transition: 0.7s
}

hr {
  margin: 20px auto;
}


/* These rules will display the [title] attribute value as text content */

i::after {
  font: 700 16px/1 Verdana;
  font-variant: small-caps;
  content: '\a0\a0'attr(title)
}


/* For Demo only */

.as-console-wrapper {
  width: 100px;
  margin-left: 80%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>

<body>


  <main>

    <i class="fa fa-play" aria-hidden="true" title="Scarface: Balls">
    <audio src="https://storage04.dropshots.com/photos7000/photos/1381926/20180317/124345.mp4" class="sound" loop></audio>
    </i>
    <br>
    <hr>

    <i class="fa fa-play" aria-hidden="true" title="Vader: CNN">
    <audio src="https://storage04.dropshots.com/photos7000/photos/1381926/20180317/124344.mp4" class="sound" loop></audio>
    </i>
    <br>
    <hr>

    <i class="fa fa-play" aria-hidden="true" title="Man of Mystery: Behave">
    <audio src="https://storage04.dropshots.com/photos7000/photos/1381926/20180317/124343.mp4" class="sound" loop></audio>
    </i>
    <br>
    <hr>

    <i class="fa fa-play" aria-hidden="true" title="Ren: Magic Nose Goblins">
    <audio src="https://storage04.dropshots.com/photos7000/photos/1381926/20180317/124342.mp4" class="sound" loop></audio>
    </i>
    <br>
    <hr>
    <i class="fa fa-play" aria-hidden="true" title="Jerky: Whatnot">
    <audio src="https://storage04.dropshots.com/photos7000/photos/1381926/20171228/181810.mp4" class="sound" loop></audio>
    </i>
    <br>

    <hr>

    <i class="fa fa-play" aria-hidden="true" title="Samuel L. Jackson: Righteous">
    <audio src="https://storage04.dropshots.com/photos7000/photos/1381926/20171228/181811.mp4" class="sound" loop></audio>
    </i>
    <br>

  </main>
  <script>
    // Collect all <i> into a NodeList then convert it into an array
    const I = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('i'));

    // Run each <i> in a loop and bind a click event to it--callback is player()
    I.forEach(function(a) {

      a.onclick = player;

    });

    function player(event) {

      // Reference the clicked <i>
      var tgt = event.target;

      // Reference the <audio> inside <i>
      var mp3 = tgt.querySelector('audio.sound');

      // if <i> has class .fa-play...
      if (tgt.classList.contains('fa-play')) {

        // play the mp3...
        mp3.play();

        // ...otherwise...
      } else {

        // pause the mp3...
        mp3.pause();

      }

      // toggle icons
      tgt.classList.toggle('fa-play');
      tgt.classList.toggle('fa-pause');

    }

    /* HTMLMediaElement.play() Returns a Promise
    || If you ever receive errors about Promises, 
    || use the following to handle Promises.
    */
    var promise = document.querySelector('audio').play();
    promise.then(_ => {
      document.querySelector('audio').pause();
      document.querySelector('audio').currentTime = '0';
      console.log('Promise Resolved');
    }).catch(error => {
      return;
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```